# android: using relative layout to position view elements inside a list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to design a list item similar to the image below ([source](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html)), using a RelativeLayout.

[image]

In my case, the itens will be:

1. ImageView (`interval_icon`)
2. Simple TextView (`interval_start`)
3. Another TextView (`interval_end`)

The code is something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:gravity="center"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/image"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:id="@+id/interval_icon"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/interval_start"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interval_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/interval_end"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="End"
        android:layout_below="@+id/interval_start"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interval_icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result is like that:

[image]

In this case the two editText are in the middle of the image.
What modification i need to do to position my itens like in the sample image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by putting TextView's in a layout and use the material design list components sheet which the link you have provided.

[image]

Here is what I did to make it Material

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/interval_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_heart_48d" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/interval_start"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:text="Start"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="72dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/interval_end"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="End"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The XML `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` makes layout to move to center of the parent layout vertically. Further adding some paddings to meet Material Guidelines gives it required look and feel. And also you can make changes to size of `ImageView` or `TextView` as you want despite guidelines followed in code.

Cheers, Gaurav

Comment: I appreciate your help and tips Gaurav. Maybe i haven't expressed well, but the i want to place the textView interval_end in the position 3 on the first picture, that is below the textView interval_start, but not as a secondary text. I goind to edited my question to explain where i want to put the view elements.

Comment: So you mean you want 4 TextViews and 1 image, right?

Comment: I`ve just edited the question (change the image and place the ids of the views on the itens 1, 2 and 3).

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/interval_icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/interval_start"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/interval_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interval_icon"
    android:text="Start" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/interval_end"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/interval_start"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interval_icon"
    android:text="End" />
```